# ajaxfileupload multiple inputs on page

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using ajaxFileUpload as described here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

It is working fine except when I have multiple file upload controls on the same page.  Specifically, I am trying to upload different files for different questions.  When I upload the first on the page, it works fine, but the one lower down on the page will only upload it's file into the answer for the first question.

I'm not sure that makes sense... so it may help you to know that my page is populated with questions dynamically using ascx files.  The document ascx file looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Document.ascx.cs" Inherits="ScholarshipApplication.controls.questions.Document" %>


<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete"  ID="FileUploadControl" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="png,jpg,jpeg,pdf,tiff,tif,gif" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="downloadButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="downloadButton_Click" />
```

And the code behind:

```
public void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            entry.data = e.FileName;
            entry.setDocumentData(e.GetContents());

            this.downloadButton.Text = e.FileName;
        }
```

My initial thoughts are that somehow I need to help the control's generated javascript to know which question it should be triggering when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in control or this was implemented by some non-obvious reason. Actually, this control doesn't support multiple instances on a page. Consider to use [AsyncFileUpload  control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) instead or customize a bit sources of the `AjaxFileUpload` control. If you prefer second option then you need to download sources from here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest and change  AjaxFileUpload.cs file (here is a path: `/Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.cs`). What you need to do is to change `ContextKey` constant to property for combining context key guid with unique id of control:

```
public class AjaxFileUpload : ScriptControlBase
{
    private const string ContextKeySuffix = "{DA8BEDC8-B952-4d5d-8CC2-59FE922E2923}";

    private string ContextKey
    {
        get { return this.UniqueID + "_" + ContextKeySuffix; }
    }
```

Actually, if you'll look on `PreRender` method of `AjaxFileUpload` class you'll easy realize reson for such behavior of this control (the first control handle uploads from all sibling controls on a page).

Comment: Wow! Your answer is well thought out.  I went ahead and switched over to AsyncFileUpload and found it to work very well.  I'll give the source code a try down the road, but this works for now.  Thanks!

Comment: Yuriy Rozhovetskiy Thanks for your answer...I don't know how to implement the above code..Can u suggest me

Comment: I have changed source code as you said, but how can i use that source code and where to build ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296308/modifying-ajaxtoolkit-source-code

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding You need a hidden field variable to identify your question id IN UserControl:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnQuestionId" runat="server"/>
```

while populating/generating question you need to set this variable , and when you upload the doc , fetch this hidden value and use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution.  How do I use this hidden value?  Can you please offer a little code example?

Comment: @mcfea Am also having same problem.. can you say how to edit the source code of ajax and use it

Comment: @VigneshKumar, It's been a long time since I've looked at this code.  I switched to the AsyncFileUpload Control per Yuriy Rozhovetskiy's comment above.  I never actually got around to modifying the source code as Async worked for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a data attribute named "data-upload-type" on ALL AjaxFileUpload controls and set it to the name of the type. Then I set up the client call to grab that value and set a cookie with the same value. The cookie IS received on the server side functions and I branch based on the value I receive.

Here is an example:

```
function StartUpload(sender, args) {
    var t = $(sender._element).attr('data-upload-type');
    document.cookie = 'upload-type=' + $(sender._element).attr('data-upload-type') + ';';
}

<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="afuUploader1" runat="server"  OnClientUploadStart="StartUpload" OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" data-upload-type="UploadType2"></asp:AjaxFileUpload>
```

Then in your server side upload call simply check Response.Cookies("upload-type").
Works like a charm!