# Multi ajax file upload based on dropdown selection asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Based on dropdown i'm getting value and need to use for ajax file upload, now the problem is that i'm getting value properly, i'm using two ajax file upload(ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete & ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete), whenever i click the upload control for uploading files from the both the control goes to one upload method(ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete) only for uploading files. I need a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

In .cs

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session["Value"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }

protected void ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        String value = Session["Value"].ToString();
    }

 protected void ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        String value1 = Session["Value"].ToString();
    }
```

In .aspx

```
 <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" ThrobberID="1" ContextKeys="1"  OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete" runat="server"/>

 <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload2" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"  ThrobberID="2"  MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" ContextKeys="2" OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload2_OnUploadComplete" runat="server" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148071/360171

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy I already gone through with that, and found cannot have one or more ajaxfileupload in same page. So i left this concept, anyhow thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it a bug in the AjaxFileUpload  I asked about this before and never got any reply except work a workaround here is the solution for this.

```
private string ContextKey = "";
public AjaxFileUpload()
            : base(true, HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"] + 1;
            }

            ContextKey = HttpContext.Current.Items["lastAjaxFileUploadContextKey"].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: in the main file constructor

Comment: sorry i couldn't get you, can you explain me in detail that what do you mean by main file??

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced the same problem, so just I removed the second Ajaxfileupload control , and I upload the files based on the dropdown selected value. I am just using single fileupload control, and add the Dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event, in that you set the path accordinglny.