# Two AjaxFileUpload controls entering the same UploadComplete function

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajaxuploader

I'm trying to use two Ajaxfileupload controls in the same page, but both enter the same uploadcomplete function and I have no idea why..
(They enter the "AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" function)

**here is my aspx part:**

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"/>        

<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload2" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_prof_pic" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"/>
```

**and here is my code behind:**

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Member_Data/" + id + "/images/"));
        string filePath = "~/Member_Data/" + id + "/images/";
        string path = filePath + e.FileName;
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath) + e.FileName);

        db1.insert_pic_slide(id, path);

        string qstring = "?id=" + id;

        //Response.Redirect("profile_layout.aspx" + qstring);

    }

    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_prof_pic(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Member_Data/" + id + "/images/"));
        string filePath = "~/Member_Data/" + id + "/images/";
        string path = filePath + e.FileName;
        AjaxFileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath) + e.FileName);

        db1.insert_pic(id, path);

        string qstring = "?id=" + id;

        Response.Redirect("profile_layout.aspx" + qstring);


    }
```

Comment: When you comment out the first one, does the second one enter `AjaxFileUpload1_prof_pic` or does it enter `Uploadcomplete`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132165/ajaxfileupload-multiple-inputs-on-page/14148071#14148071

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced the same problem, so just I removed the second Ajaxfileupload control , and I upload the files based on the dropdown selected value. I am just using single fileupload control.