# Modifying AjaxToolkit Source Code

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have decided to make some changes in source code of ajaxFileUpload but i don know after making changes how can I use that.

How to build that and add the newly modified file to ajax library.

I have googled about this but dint get any solution.

I need help regarding this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4pm/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4pm/33/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

***`You can make the change in the .js file but make sure to recomplie and add the newly compiled .dll to your project.  I think if you found a problem with browsers and know the problem, I'd suggest submitting the fix on Code Plex so it can be included for everyone vs. creating your own version.  This way when a new version comes out you don't have to refix the problem before adding the new features.`***

Comment: I have downloaded source code from CodePlex and Modified.What should i do now?

Comment: Whatever you want to change you must change its .js(For ex: ModalPopupBehavior.js) file and recompile it and post it to codeplex.

Comment: I need to change it in .Cs file

Comment: This article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37543/How-to-Customize-the-New-AjaxControlToolkit-Tools might be helpful for you..please check